# Log4j2: Logger is configured but not usable

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I'm working on a JEE REST API and am converting to log4j2. Some of my logging is working, but not others.

I created an appender, monitorAppender. Here's its configuration:

```
<RollingFile name="monitorAppender" append="true" fileName="${baseDir}/ZDA_monitor.log" filePattern="${baseDir}/ZDA_monitor.log.%i">
    <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyMMddHHmmssSSS}|%m%x%n"/>
    <Policies>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
    </Policies>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5"/>
</RollingFile>
```

And logger configuration:

```
<Logger name="ZDAMonitor" level="info" additivity="false">
    <AppenderRef ref="monitorAppender"/>
</Logger>
```

In my code when I try to use the logger:

```
LogManager.getLogger("ZDAMonitor").fatal("Test123");
```

I see this in the console, instead of the file:

`SystemOut     O 14:56:50.922 [WebContainer : 1] FATAL ZDAMonitor - Test123`

I can't tell what's wrong with the config. I turned on debug logging for log4j and see in the startup logs it's being correctly loaded:

`SystemOut     O 2023-01-25 14:56:43,490 WebContainer : 1 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=5745d2fa,component=Loggers,name=ZDAMonitor`

I can't post the source as this is a company project, but I'm using gradle, log4j-core and api 2.19.0, and WebSphere 8.5.5.22 with Java 1.8.

I've checked and double checked the configuration and code, and cannot find anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere has a very peculiar thread context classloader.

The `log4j-web` module configures a logger context associated to the context classloader. However the context classloader in WebSphere is **not** the classloader that loaded the classes in your application, so your application's loggers use a different logger context (and a different config). See [LOG4J2-3577](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3577) for details.

A simple solution would be to use a [`BasicContextSelector`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html#ContextSelector).

Comment: Thank you! Would that be done by setting a system property, e.g. `System.setProperty("log4j2.contextSelector", "org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.BasicContextSelector");` ?

Comment: Yes, although I would keep the change local by putting it in a `log4j2.component.properties` file (cf. [System properties](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#SystemProperties)).

Comment: Is there an easy way to determine if the `BasicContextSelector` is being used? I'm not noticing any difference after implementing that.

Comment: I was able to implement it by setting a system property. Unfortunately it actually breaks some logging and doesn't fix other logging.

Comment: When you run with `-Dlog4j2.debug=true` the name of the `LoggerContext` should always be the same if you use `BasicContextSelector`.

Comment: If you are still interested, I finally got things working. I was trying to load the configuration file via `Configurator.initialize()` but that was not working. What I should have done is set the system property `log4j2.configurationFile` to the name of my property file (as the documentation instructs...)